# Why am I getting a warning when I try to count a mysqli result?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, count

The code below causes this warning:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Why does it do that? How can I prevent the warning?

```
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $sonum = $_GET['edit'];
    $update = true;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM salesorder WHERE sonum=$sonum") or die ($mysqli->error);

    if (count($result)==1) {
        $row = $result->fetch_array();
        $salesperson = $row['salesperson'];
        $company = $row['company'];
        $status = $row['status'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result` will either be a `mysqli_result` object or `bool`. (See "[Return Values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues)" in the `mysqli_query` documentation.) Neither of those are countable. Newer PHP versions warn you when you try to count a non-countable thing, even though `count()` will still return a value (for now!)

That `if (count($result)==1) {` wouldn't have given that warning in PHP versions < 7.2, but it never really did anything, because `count($result)` would always be 1 whether the query failed or not. You might not expect it to be so, but `count(false)` returns 1. That's part of the reason it's a good thing that `count()` gives that warning now.

If you're just trying to set those variables if the query returned any rows, you can do it like this:

```
if ($result && $row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $salesperson = $row['salesperson'];
    $company = $row['company'];
    $status = $row['status'];
}
```

---

By the way, you should take a look at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and fix the injection vulnerability at  `...WHERE sonum=$sonum"`. You should use a prepared statement and bind `$sonum` rather than including it in the SQL string.